# Understanding my case insensitive list comparison

Tags: python, list, case

I'm working through the Python Crash Course book. I was doing one of the exercises that I mostly managed to figure out. There is just one bit of code that I can't seem to get.

The exercise:

> Compare two lists, one of `current_users` one of `new_users`. Make sure they are case insensitive.

I want to know why when I convert `current_users` to lowercase, is `'andy657'` still being read as available when printed the first time?

The Code:

```
current_users = ['nedboy78', 'codingking678', 'johnnykapahala','jam95','python65','ANDY657']
new_users = ['hamlet56', 'python65', 'jam95','todds4','andy657']

current_users_convert = [current_user.lower() for current_user in current_users]

for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user in current_users:
        print("sorry username " + new_user + ' not available pick a new username')
    else:
        print("username " + new_user + ' is available')

    if new_user in current_users_convert:
        print("CANT USE " + new_user + " AS A USERNAME")
```

The Output:

```
username hamlet56 is available
sorry username python65 not available pick a new username
CANT USE python65 AS A USERNAME
sorry username jam95 not available pick a new username
CANT USE jam95 AS A USERNAME
username todds4 is available
username andy657 is available
CANT USE andy657 AS A USERNAME
```

Comment: `print("username " + new_user + ' is available')` is not properly indented to be in the `else` clause

Comment: why would it not? you don't have that print statement in any condition, so it would always execute.

Comment: This code won't compile as written. Even if the indentation is fixed, the two `if` statements aren't logically connected and aren't disjoint. You probably want to lowercase both lists, then use a single `if`-`else`.

Comment: If you want to compare this list, you can do `list(set(current_users_convert ) & set(new_users ))`, to get the available user names.

Comment: Sorry that was a type error on my part. It is compiled correctly in editor, I typed it wrong in here. Fixed now, but I still can't figure out why i'm getting 'andy657'

Comment: Also, if you haven't seen it already solutions for Python Crash Course exercises are available online. This code looks like it's from the first edition of the book, and the solutions for that book are [here](http://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc/solutions/README.html). Solutions for the second edition are [here](https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc_2e/solutions/solutions/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your `else` condition executes before the last `if` condition. So here I have change the order.

```
current_users = ['nedboy78', 'codingking678', 'johnnykapahala','jam95','python65','ANDY657']
new_users = ['hamlet56', 'python65', 'jam95','todds4','andy657']

current_users_convert = [current_user.lower() for current_user in current_users]
for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user in current_users:
        print(f'sorry username {new_user} not available pick a new username')

    elif new_user in current_users_convert:
        print(f"CANT USE {new_user} AS A USERNAME")

    else:
        print(f'username {new_user} is available')
```

Output:

```
username hamlet56 is available
sorry username python65 not available pick a new username
sorry username jam95 not available pick a new username
username todds4 is available
CANT USE andy657 AS A USERNAME
```